# How to hide textboxes, labels and buttons C# WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visibility

I would like to hide several textboxes, a label and a button as soon as a button is clicked... however, for some reason, my code doesn't seem to cause this effect. Nothing appears to happen. I'm using WPF.

Here is my code:

```
private void doSomething_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Name.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; 

    }
```

This code doesn't seem to work.. any ideas?

Comment: what does your code do? anything? nothing? Have you tried Visibility.Collapsed? Can you confirm your code is actually being executed? - try setting a breakpoint or tracepoint.

Comment: @CollinE, it currently does nothing. Yes, i put a break-point and i stepped through it. It does go through each line but nothing happens on the Form itself =/ I have tried .Collapsed as well. Same issue...

Comment: that looks as though it should work... Are you doing anything special in your xaml? Can you post the xaml?

Comment: @wdavo, sure, i've posted my XAML ... i haven't directly edited this code at all as of yet..

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue or not but the control names in your code don't seem to match those in your xaml

Comment: oh, i changed the name when i posted the example of .hidden... but in my code they are actually the same .. =/ hmm i can't seem to figure it out.. i can make forms disappear and re-appear.. just not textboxes..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine, the "Signing in..." label appears after everything else disappear. I suggest you to just copy all your code from the .xaml.cs file and the .xaml file into a new project, but make sure you don't copy the first line`"<Window x:Class="..."` because it could generate an error if the class name isn't the same in the new project.

For the xaml code I suggest you not think the same as you design windows forms applications. WPF has the layout system, which re-orientates or re-sizes its elements when re-sizing the window. So you should not specify exact numbers in the margin property as if they where coordinates. Create a grid, create rows or columns for each element and then just set the horizontal or vertical alignment or margins. Think different than the old windows forms way.

Comment: thanks, i'll do that. Glad that it works... sad that i have to re-make it again though... =/

Comment: :( doesn't seem to want to work for me.. even after creating a new project.

Answer (score 18):

I believe `Visibility.Collapsed` is what you need and not `Visibility.Hidden`.

EDIT: Did you try follow up this code with `UpdateLayout()` method of parent element/component?

Answer (score 4):

I've run your code... and it's working great for me. I've not changed anything (except the variable names) so I guess it's a bug from VS.

As said [nikolamm94](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1056915/nikolamm94) try to add `this.UpdateLayout();` at the end of `connect_Click` it might help. I tried and it is still working fine. Or maybe create a new VS projet, it already worked for me a few times.

Sorry my answer is not the most helpful, I wanted to put a comment instead but I don't have enough reputation :/

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this... :( sucks that i have to remake it. But i'm glad it works... hope it looked good when u ran it :)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748821(v=vs.85).aspx

Set to Visible: tb1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

Set to Hide: tb1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;

Answer (score -1):

You can hide a textbox by going to properties->appearance->visibility, then setting it to "hidden"